# Easiest way to SEARCH a Ruby array for a VALUE? (And delete specific array elements)

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, data-structures, counter

I'm a new Ruby programmer performing an exercise to make a program that lets people play fish.  I'm building a method that will search for books and handle them when it finds them.  I have my player hands stored in an array, so I want to search them for matches.

My 2 questions are:

1. What is the easiest, most effective and simplest way to search
   through an array?
2. When I find 4 of a certain element in the same array, what is the
   best way to delete those elements from the array?

I need to:

- **SEARCH the array** for each element of `%w(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A)
  #Values for cards`,  (I'm going to use a do each iterator for this, I got that).  **I need to know how to search the array in the first place.**
- Count each time I come across a match for the element
- If count == 4, I have a book so I need to know **how to delete specific elements of the array** #(the 4 matching cards)

I know this is simple stuff, so thanks for the help and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for elements in an array you can make use of select (alias find_all). Select will loop through and "select" elements that match conditions in the provided block, returning "selected" elements in an array.

Example:

```
['2', '3', '4'].select { |card|  card == '2'  }   #=> ["2"]
```

You could also remove the need to search through an array by using a hash instead (mapping card values to the number of cards). This would allow you to easily check how many cards of a certain type a hand contains (see below for an example).

To count each time you come across an element you will need some data structure to store a card value and a count. A hash would be a good option here.

Example: card value => count

```
{ '2' => 1 }
```

To delete elements from an array you can use #delete or #delete_at to delete elements based on value or elements based on their array index. Another option is to use bang methods like #select! to transform your current array based on a provided block. Ruby has plenty of options for tasks like this.

I'd recommend skimming through methods for Array and Enumerable to get a better handle on what can be done with arrays. It's well worth your time as a lot of Ruby's power and elegance lies with Array and Enumerable.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I just use that with `.size` and it works well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lots of overly complex answers.

Want to know if an element is in an array? Use `include?`.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].include?(4) # true
[1, 2, 3, 4].include?(5) # false
```

Want to delete all instances of a value from an array? Use `delete`

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.delete(4) # 4
x # [1, 2, 3]

y = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
y.delete(4) # nil
y # [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
y.delete(2) # 2
y # [1, 1, 3, 3]
```

If you want to count the number of times a term appears, use `count`:

```
x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
x.count('a') # 2
x.count('b') # 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity, the delete method works great.  **However** the include method only returns if the array **has** the element, not **how many** times the element appears within the array.  Got anything for that?

Comment: Thanks for the delete method!

Comment: @Yallo Yes, use `count` to find out **how many** times the element appears in the array. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at enumerable module. There is pretty neat documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html My advise is to scan all the methods in this module as they are all extremely useful. For your task I would probably use `count` method. If you want to count all cards, `group_by` is what you want. Together with `map` you can do:

```
hand = [2,3,6,10,2,J,A,3,J,2,K,K,2]
Hash[hand.group_by{|value| value}.map{|key, values| [key, values.count]}]
# => {2 => 4, 3 => 2, 6 => 1, 10 => 1, J => 2, A => 1, K => 2}
```